# Trigger Lync message from Sharepoint List?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, lync

Is there any way to trigger a lync message to a predefined user group from a SharePoint list?

Say I wanted to open a Lync "chat" with Paul, Peter and Sofia whenever a new item is being created in a list. I would of cause need to define somewhere what field should be send to them.

I don't expect it to be possible, but though I'd ask here.

Answer (score 0):

Server and client contexts are two different things and they are not aware of each other. In other words, server side code won't be able to start a client application.

On the other hand, there is a thing called **Auto-Contact URL** in Lync. So you best approach is generating an Auto-Contact URL (which would start a chat with required users) in an event receiver (server side) and email that URL to your inbox. The chat would then start when you click on that URL (client side).

Another way would be setting Auto-Contact URL to one of the hyperlink columns and sending an email (to yourself or other users) with the link to the list item that was just added. Then, after opening the form, you would just need to click on the generated hyperlink.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The usecase would be to use Lync to inform users about any relevant updates to the list (Rather than emails). But for it to work it would need to work without any interaction from the end users. I don't have high hopes for this to be possible though.